# Rename x,y vectors in t-test R

Tags: r

I am performing a t-test in R

```
out <- t.test(x=input1, y=input2, alternative=c("two.sided","less","greater"), mu=0, paired=TRUE, conf.level = 0.95)
```

It gives the result

```
Paired t-test

data:  input1 and input2
t = -1.1469, df = 7, p-value = 0.2891
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.15100900  0.05236717 
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
            -0.04932091
```

I need to change the names of the data in result. e.g.,

> data:  Fruits and Vegetables

Please, anyone give me an idea to include some attribute in t.test to change the data names.

Comment: What are `input1` and `input2`? If these are vectors, rename them to "Fruits" and "Vegetables".

Comment: By the way, you do not need the `mu = 0`, nor `conf.level = 0.95` as those are the defaults in `t.test()` and the `alternative` argument requires a character vector of length 1 - the `"less"` and `"greater"` are ignored. In that case you want `alternative = "two.sided"` not all three. Replace `"two.sided"` with one of the other two types of hypothesis is that is what you want.

Comment: Yes, those are vectors. Thanks for your suggestions. I will do accordingly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some dummy data

```
set.seed(1)
input1 <- rnorm(20, mean = -1)
input2 <- rnorm(20, mean = 5)
```

It would be easier just to rename or create objects with the desired names:

```
Fruits <- input1
Vegetables <- input2

t.test(x = Fruits, y = Vegetables, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")

    Paired t-test

data:  Fruits and Vegetables 
t = -18.6347, df = 19, p-value = 1.147e-13
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.454791 -5.151218 
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -5.803005
```

But if you really want to do this after the fact, then grab the object returned by `t.test()`:

```
tmp <- t.test(x = input1, y = input2, paired = TRUE, alternative = "two.sided")
```

Look at the structure of the object `tmp`

```
> str(tmp)
List of 9
 $ statistic  : Named num -18.6
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
 $ parameter  : Named num 19
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
 $ p.value    : num 1.15e-13
 $ conf.int   : atomic [1:2] -6.45 -5.15
  ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
 $ estimate   : Named num -5.8
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of the differences"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "difference in means"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Paired t-test"
 $ data.name  : chr "input1 and input2"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

and note the `data.name` component. We can replace that with a character string:

```
tmp$data.name <- "Fuits and Vegetables"
```

The print `tmp`:

```
> tmp

    Paired t-test

data:  Fuits and Vegetables 
t = -18.6347, df = 19, p-value = 1.147e-13
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0 
95 percent confidence interval:
 -6.454791 -5.151218 
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -5.803005
```